# Can't find the source code of the Android system implementation of an abstract class of the framework

Tags: android

I need all the details of `startActivity(Intent intent, Bundle options)`, to debug my app. I've already read [its documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent,%20android.os.Bundle)), but I'd like to gain deeper understanding by examining its source code, to see the exact logic of the method. I've found [`android.content.Context` on googlesource.com](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-mr1-release/core/java/android/content/Context.java), but "*This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system.*". I can't find the source code of that implementation.

Comment: In android studio you can press CTRL +point your cursor on `startActivity(Intent intent, Bundle options)`  and click you can see source code of that class also

Comment: @SAKhan Pressing `CTRL` while pointing my cursor on `startActivity` in `MyMainActivity.java` links to _path\to\sdk\on\my\pc_ \sources\android-21\ **android\app\Activity.java**. Its line #4050 shows the code, so this seems to be a good soultion, thank you. The link in the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54570809/1293492) shows a different source, I don't know why, but I'll find out soon...

Comment: it depends on sdk and compile sdk version.
if you want to find source code of anty method or class of your project with method with help you.it is dynamic

Comment: It's really useful. The only thing I don't understand currently, is this: not only the version is different, but also the class. Your solution shows a local equivalent of [**app/Activity.java**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#4001) in Android Studio, the other solution shows [**app/ContextImpl.java**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#1229) in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [`ContextImpl`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-9.0.0_r22/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#898) class which is inherited from `Context`

Comment: Replace `android-9.0.0_r22` with `pie-release` (API 26), `nougat-release` (API 24) `lollipop-mr1-release` (API 22), you get the gist. You're now in the implementation part which changes with each release. Only the API si stable. And remember that OEMs can alter their implementations to some extent.

Comment: Thank you Saurabh Thorat and Eugen Pechanec, this is what I was looking for. I need API 21, so I've replaced `android-9.0.0_r22` with (the hopefully correct) `lollipop-release` after browsing through the [full list of branches](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+refs), and updating the line number to 1229 in the URL's hash portion. It [works](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#1229) perfectly.